# Android Sharing a PDF File to another app under SDK 27

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

Recently upgraded to SDK 27 and now my file sharing capability is broken. The idea is for a user to hit the "share file" button, Android shows them available applications and they choose one to attach the selected PDF file to that application. So for example, if they choose GMail, the file would be attached, they would enter the subject, "to" address and submit it.

The original problem was that the `uri.parse` method was deprecated (I assume for security reasons) and has now been replaced by `FileProvider.getUriForFile` which has worked for other scenarios in the application (loading and saving media files) but in this case GMail starts but the attachment never gets attached. No errors are thrown.

Is is still possible to attach files this way under SDK 28?

Here is the code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File output = new File(pdfFilePath);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    MyActivity.this,
    MyActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", output);
shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

I have verified the file exists, the path being:

```
 /storage/emulated/0/myapp/8d7a79dd-2c23-49c3-bd36-68335d418268.pdf
```

The generated URI is not null and have the following in the uriString in the debugger:

```
content://com.mycompany.myapp.provider/external_files/myapp/8d7a79dd-2c23-49c3-bd36-68335d418268.pdf
```

Is Android expecting some other pattern? Testing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 running Android 8.

Comment: Do you have configuration file for FileProvider in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

So suddenly this is working. I am thinking the Debugger or something got corrupted. Cleaned, rebuilt and re-started Android Studio and suddenly all is well. I will leave this here just for example purposes.